# UIActivityViewController PDF only working in the simulator

Tags: ios, pdf, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a little problem here. I'm trying to make a UIActivityViewController, where the user can send a PDF (generated by the App) by E-mail or print it with AirPrint. What I have made seems to work in the simulator. I get the mail view with a file attached, and I have succeeded in printing the PDF from the simulator too. But when I test it on my iPhone (5 with iOS 7.1), the UIActivityViewController just say "No share actions available" and provides a cancel button only.

**This is the code:**

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"File.pdf"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: pdfData, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can someone spot the error??

Comment: You have to specify the complete path to the file when you call `dataWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: And where are you putting this PDF file? Make sure it's not in the app bundle. That will work on the Simulator but not on a real iOS device.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The problem was the complete path. When i look at the simulator's directory, the file appeared in the Documents folder when generated. The simulator didn't care, but the iPhone got confused. Thanks :)